# Can I manually delete older version of Windows 10 SDK?

Tags: visual-studio-2022, windows-10-sdk

Currently as it stands, I only have Windows 10 SDK 10.0.19041.0 installed, and this is after I uninstalled older versions of Windows 10 SDK.

One can check in the Visual Studio Installer that I *really* only have **Windows 10 SDK 10.0.19041.0** installed

[image]

The problem is that as shown above, at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib`, I still have older Windows 10 SDK folders available. They use up quite a lot of spaces ( around 1.6 GB++) and I want to free them.

I tried to use Add/Remove Program to Remove the older versions of Windows 10 SDK, and it said "removed error" because those older versions are no longer there.

[image]

So can I just delete those unwanted folders in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib`, without affecting my ability to develop on VS 2022?

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio 2017 or later, you should first run the **Visual Studio Installer** then uncheck the components for the Windows SDKs you don't want.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn, as you can see from my first screenshot, the components are _already_ unchecked in vs installer

Comment: If you look inside those directories, what's there? Is it the full SDK or just parts of it?

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn, how can I tell whether it's partial or full?

Comment: Just look to see if it's a few files or lots of them...

Answer (score 1):

Archive and delete the folders from what you don't need.
Just in case it breaks something, you can restore from archive.

If everything works fine for a longer period, delete the archive.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Restart the computer
2. Run the tool to allow uninstallation issues, [tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed-cca7d1b6-65a9-3d98-426b-e9f927e1eb4d).
3. Try uninstall from control panel.
4. If it fails, use [this](https://wixtoolset.org/) to find the product code or any other tool.
5. Run msiexec on the command prompt under admin to uninstall it

> msiexec /X {product code}